# Pure state density-operator can not be expressed as non trivial linear combination

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, trace, quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

**Basic Definitions:**

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. Define a density operator $\rho \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ (continous linear operators from $\mathcal{H}$ into itself) by

1. $\rho$ is self-adjoint
2. $\rho$ is positive
3. $\mathrm{tr} \rho=1$.

A density operator is called a pure state, if it is the projection onto a one dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{H}$.

This is equivalent to $\mathrm{tr} \rho^2=\mathrm{tr}\rho$.

**The Problem:**

I want to prove that $\rho$ is a pure state $\Leftrightarrow$ $\rho$ can not be expressed as a nontrivial linear combination of density operators.

**What i have done:**

I have allready proven $\Leftarrow$ by showing that every mixed (non-pure) state is the non trivial convex linear combination of other density operators.

I am stuck on $\Rightarrow$. I have proven, that a pure state cannot be expressed as a nontrivial **convex** linear combination of density operators. I did this by showing the convexity of $\mathrm{tr} \rho^2$.

Let $ ̣\rho= \lambda \rho_1 +(1- \lambda) \rho_2$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $\rho_1,\rho_2$ density operators. Then:
$$\begin{equation}
 \label{eq:trsqkonvex}
 \begin{split}
  \mathrm{tr} \rho^{2}&\leq  \lambda^{2} \mathrm{tr} \rho_1^{2} +2 \lambda (1-\lambda) \sqrt{\mathrm{tr} \rho_1^{2}\mathrm{tr} \rho_2^{2}} + (1-\lambda)^{2} \mathrm{tr} \rho_2^{2} \\
     &= \left( \lambda \sqrt{\mathrm{tr} \rho_1^{2}} + (1-\lambda) \sqrt{\mathrm{tr} \rho_2^{2}} \right)^{2}   \\
     &\leq \lambda \mathrm{tr} \rho_1^{2} + (1-\lambda) \mathrm{tr} \rho_2^{2} \leq 1.
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
\tag{1}
$$

Where the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality was used at the first $\leq$ and the convexity of $t \to t^2$ at the second.

**Where im stuck:**

Now i want to show $\Rightarrow$ for a general linear combination.
Its not hard to show that if $\rho = \alpha \rho_1 + \beta \rho_2$, with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$, $\rho_1,\rho_2$ density operators,
then $\alpha,\beta$ are of the form $\alpha =\lambda,\beta = (1-\lambda)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\setminus [0,1]$, then the argument i have used in Eq. 1 will break down, since $\lambda$ or $(1-\lambda)$ will have to be replaced with their absolute value.

My idea is to show that the general linear combination must be a convex one to begin with. I would be grateful for any hints or complete proofs (even alternative proofs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out i think. The statement is simply untrue.
Consider the example
$$\rho_1 =\frac{1}{2} ( | 1 \rangle \langle1| +|2 \rangle \langle 2 | ),$$
$$\rho_2 = |2 \rangle \langle 2 |. $$
Where $| i \rangle \in \mathcal{H} , i=1, 2$ are an orthonormal system.
Then
$$2 \rho_1 + (1-2)\rho_2 = | 1 \rangle \langle1|.$$
A pure state. So convexity of the lin. combination is necessary on the RHS of the problem.